# Choropleth maps not showing but white page

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to make a choropleth figure and below is my sample code:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default='browser'
vietnam_state=json.load(open("diaphantinhenglish.geojson","r"))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Ha Noi','Ha Giang','Cao Bang','Bac Kan','Tuyen Quang'],
    'Count': [3757,26,43,27,208]})

#df
Name    Count
0   Ha Noi  3757
1   Ha Giang    26
2   Cao Bang    43
3   Bac Kan 27
4   Tuyen Quang 208

fig=px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=vietnam_state,
    featureidkey="properties.Name",
    locations="Name",
    color='Count',
    title="ABC",
    color_continuous_scale="Aggrnyl")

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations",visible=False)
fig.show()
```

It's worked on my laptop with internet connection as below:
[image]

But on my PC without internet connection, maps doesn't show and below is console:
[image]

So I would like to ask what should I do. Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

- have amended your code to make it simpler to run (sources geojson and constructs a dataframe for all states)
- when I switch off my internet,  it still works (if there is a local copy of geojson)

  1. is your PC plotly installation unto date? I'm using 5.3.1
  2. it's maybe a caching issue, can you connect your PC to internet, run.  Then go offline. (I have also cleared my caches, still runs)

```
import requests, json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from pathlib import Path

# fmt: off
f = Path().cwd().joinpath("diaphantinhenglish.geojson")
if not f.exists():
    res = requests.get("https://data.opendevelopmentmekong.net/dataset/999c96d8-fae0-4b82-9a2b-e481f6f50e12/resource/2818c2c5-e9c3-440b-a9b8-3029d7298065/download/diaphantinhenglish.geojson")
    with open(f, "w") as fh: json.dump(res.json(), fh)

with open(f) as fh: vietnam_state = json.load(fh)
# construct values for all states...
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": pd.json_normalize(vietnam_state["features"]).loc[:, "properties.Name"].values}
).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(Count=np.random.randint(20, 4000, len(d))))
# fmt: on

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=vietnam_state,
    featureidkey="properties.Name",
    locations="Name",
    color="Count",
    title="ABC",
    color_continuous_scale="Aggrnyl",
)

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, as I said it's worked on may laptop with internet access but PC still didn't T.T;  I think I have to download js file and paste them to same folder with py file.